# How do I remove echo from an audio recording?

Tags: audio-recording, noise-cancelling, echo

I'm working with the audio file of a drama recorded in a hall where most of the dialog has an echo. Not as bad as a stadium echo, but significant nonetheless.

Since it is in the foreign language, I am trying to learn, I need it to be as clear as possible.  I've tried a number of techniques and filters with a variety of programs.

Sadly, no success.

Any advice on how to removing this echo?

Answer (score 5):

It's not really possible to remove it completly. You could use a gate, but that would not remove any echo trailing into the voice. If you have an impulse signature you could reverse engineer the echo, but for what you want to do, it seems like you should get a better audio source.

Answer (score 3):

Try a transient designer or enveloper. Don't expect perfect results, but they will work better than a standard gate on dynamic signals like voice.